# Alamofire http post - Registering user Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire, postman

Quick question: I'm registering a user to my database using Alamofire library. I got the endpoint and parameters from the backend developer and tested it in Postman myself and data is passing fine. I'm implementing it in my Register View Controller but been getting no response. Here is my implementation. FYI: I left user type off the View Controller. The end user is not supposed to know they are user type 3. I may be doing something wrong here. I'm not getting back no response in the output.

```
let params = ["username":usernameField.text!,
                  "firstname":firstNameField.text!,
                  "lastname":lastNameField.text!,
                  "password":passwordField.text!,
                  "usertype":"3",
                  "email":emailAddressField.text!
    ]

    let apiMethod = "http://api.example.com"

    Alamofire.request(apiMethod, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseString { (response) in

        print(response);

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert);

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default,handler: nil));

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }



}

       if let json = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, String> {
           print ("JSON: \(json)")
           if (json["register_status"]! == "userExist") {
                return
        } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerSuccess", sender: self)
           }
          }
```

Once the user has registered properly, my response should be:

```
{
  "username": "userregister",
  "register_status": "RegistrationComplete",
  "register_date": "11/10/2016"
}
```

But if user exists then I would get back this message:

```
{
  "username": "userregister",
  "register_status": "userExist",
  "register_date": "11/10/2016"
}
```

What am I doing wrong in my Swift 3 code?

Edit (Adding Register View Controller) for clarity:
[image: Register View Controller for the above swift code]

Comment: what is the error you are getting right now?

Comment: *I left user type off the View Controller. The end user is not supposed to know they are user type 3.* What do you mean!? rephrase please

Comment: @Honey I edited my post to show the view controller for clarity. The end user is signing up as a customer (UserType 3). Hope this gives you a better understanding.

Comment: @hacker_1989 I'm not getting back any errors at all.

Comment: You should explicitly set your params to `params: [String: Any]` since that's what the request expects.

Answer (score 1):

I will something like this if your response is JSON. This will help you debug the code. Also, I would suggest you put breakpoints and check for response in console.

```
Alamofire.request(apiMethod, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON {response in
    var err:Error?
    switch response.result {
    case .success(let json):
         print(json)
          // update UI on main thread
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert);

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default,handler: nil));

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } 
    case .failure(let error):
         err = error
         print(err)
    }
}
```

If this doesn't help you, please share your rest client request payload so that I can help you further.

Comment: hello my url is https://api.example.com then i found {
    response =     {
        code = 301;
        msg = "wrong url";
        success = f;
        "success_ios" = 0;
    };
} what can i do please suggest me ..

Comment: 301 is url not found. Please make sure you have the correct url. Can you share more code?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is made on another thread, so you need to wrap your alert controller presentation call in a DispatchQueue.main.async block because all ui needs to happen on the main thread or you can get weird drawing/timing errors.

Anyways thats likely not the problem with your request.  You are making a http request which is now disabled by default as of iOS 9.  You need to explicitly set the app transport security keys in your info.plist file.  You can see the values in the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html).  I am guessing you probably want both NSAllowsArbitraryLoads and NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads.

Comment: Hey Josh, I did that already. I have other forms within the app making requests through the Alamofire library. Not sure what's the issue with this one.

Comment: are you sure the request is actually being made then?  put a  break before the alamofire request and inside of it.  Even if it time's out and fails you should still get a response with an error instead of data.  The default timeout is 60 seconds, so wait and see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the assistance @hacker_1989 @Josh @Aaron yesterday. My solution to the registration of user using Alamofire Library with Swift 3 language is as below:

```
@IBAction func registerTappedButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if(userNameField.text == nil || (userNameField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        self.showAlertError("Username required", message: "")
        return
    }
    if(firsNameField.text == nil || (firsNameField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        self.showAlertError("First Name required", message: "")
        return

    }
    if(lastNameField.text == nil || (lastNameField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        self.showAlertError("Last Name required", message: "")
        return
    }
    if(passwordField.text == nil || (passwordField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        self.showAlertError("Password required", message: "")
        return
    }
    if(emailAddressField.text == nil || (emailAddressField.text?.isEmpty)!) {
        self.showAlertError("Email Address required", message: "")
    }

    let params = ["username": userNameField.text!,
                  "firstname": firsNameField.text!,
                  "lastname": lastNameField.text!,
                  "password": passwordField.text!,
                  "usertype": 3,
                  "email": emailAddressField.text!] as [String : Any]

    let apiMethod = "http://api.example.com" //<-Set your endpoint here

    Alamofire.request(apiMethod, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString { (response) in

        print(response);

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL!", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert);

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default,handler: nil));



        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

The backend developer changed the endpoint to expect JSON object. He had set the endpoint to expect URL Encoded parameters before.

Now everything is working fine. Data is passing successfully.